# How can I pass arguments into node.js javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am totally new to node and I have been reading the process api from the site. However I do not think I have the context down yet so any help on getting a better understanding.

I want to pass an argument into my node script, so from the command line it would look like node connecttoerver.js -ip 192.10.10.1. I have the code below that kind of works but even reading the docs I do not know what is going on here.

```
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is from the [node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv), so the `process.argv` (argv stands for arguments vector) is

> An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file. The next elements will be any additional command line arguments.

so the output for `connecttoerver.js -ip 192.10.10.1` is going to be:

```
0: node
1: path/to/connecttoerver.js
2: --=ip
3: 192.10.10.1
```

`process.argv` is just an array of command line arguments passed to the script. But the first one is `node`, second is the filepath and others are arguments passed to the script separated by white space.

What you really want is a library which could parse the arguments and pass it to you in a handy way. For example with [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist) you'll get:

```
 var argv = require('optimist').argv;

 if (argv.rif - 5 * argv.xup > 7.138) {
    console.log('Test one');
 } else {
    console.log('Test two');
 }
```

Call it like

```
node xup.js --rif=55 --xup=9.52
   Test one

node xup.js --rif 12 --xup 8.1
   Test two
```

Such libraries include argument parsing, default values, making some var required, etc.

Comment: After searching I finally found this http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments

Comment: Yeah, parsing yourself is OK too for something simple. But for advanced cli options usage you'll have to write a lot of code yourself. In their article they advice using `optimist` as well.